# APIM Policy - Unable to cast object

Tags: json, azure, casting, url-rewriting, azure-api-management

I'm facing an issue when I use the APIM URL re-write policy, I need to use the suffix value from a variable. I attempted various methods but always end up with the error ***"Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.PipelineResponse' to type 'System.String"***

Here is my inbound policy:

```
 <inbound>
    <!-- Send Requst to Logic Apps to retrieve the corresponding suffix -->
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="Response_Suffix" timeout="20" ignore-error="true">
        <set-url>{{LogicAppsURL}}</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="append">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@{
                
                return new JObject(
                    new JProperty("ModelName", (context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true).SelectToken("ModelName")))).ToString();

                }</set-body>
    </send-request>
    <set-variable name="URL_Suffix" value="@((IResponse)context.Variables["Response_Suffix"])" />

    <!-- Set Backend URL -->
    <set-backend-service base-url="{{BaseURL}}" />
    <base />

    <!-- Rewrite URL -->
    <rewrite-uri template="@((string)context.Variables["URL_Suffix"])" />
</inbound>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the output of Logic Apps and had the UR_Suffix cast out as a token (string) from the json body and that apparently fixed the issue.

JSON Output:

```
{"suffix":"<value>"}
```

Modified policy:

```
 <set-variable name="URL_Suffix" value="@((((IResponse)context.Variables["Suffix_Body"]).Body.As<JObject>().SelectToken("suffix")).ToString())" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`Response_Suffix` variable is set to `IResponse` instance by `send-request` policy. Then your set-variable policy sets `URL_Suffix` variable to `IResponse` as well. And then in rewrite-url policy you cast `URL_Suffix` to `string`.

Not sure what exactly you mean by URL suffix but it's likely your set-variable policy is wrong, feels like you should be extracting some property from response, rather than whole response.